# Delphi XE7 unidac rounding issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, unidac

In my below delphi code, which is compiled in XE7 and with unidac version 7.0.2 :

```
cAmount : Currency;

cAmount := Query1.FieldByName('AMOUNT').AsCurrency;
```

Sometimes i get very weird values in cAmount.

For example if the Amount value in the database(Oracle) is 2.4,The value I'll get in cAmount is 2.3999.To my surprise i'm getting this values only sometimes when i try to recreate the scenario.

Could anyone please help me in this.

Comment: How is the field declared in the database?

Comment: @David, `AsCurrency` reads `AsFloat` which is `Double`, which "represents" real value of 2.4 like that.

Comment: This field is declared as Number

Comment: @victoria35 But not all the times I'm getting the same.Most of the time i'm getting 2.4

Comment: @Binitta, not for the same value which is actually stored.

Comment: @Victoria I didn't get you.

Comment: @Binitta, I wanted to say that there is a difference in values that you have actually stored. There is no most of the time. What you store is what you get. Here is a [story about it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @Victoria I dont thing that is the problem. Because I'm fetching same record in a Loop without any update to the record.So the value is same always in database.

Comment: @Binitta, fetching "same record in a loop" makes little sense to me, but if you can prove it in a minimal, compilable code example, edit your question and post such, please.

Comment: @Victoria AsCurrency converts decimal to binary? That's crazy.